Microsoft claims that a wchar_t can hold any Unicode character - is this true?
There are many questions on this site regarding Unicode and wchar_t. I guess I have grasped the concept, but then found something that proves most (if not all) answers wrong if it is true. On this page, Microsoft claims that one wchar_t character can hold any Unicode character (emphasis mine):

A wide character is a 2-byte multilingual character code. Any character in use in modern computing worldwide, including technical symbols and special publishing characters, can be represented according to the Unicode specification as a wide character. Developed and maintained by a large consortium that includes Microsoft, the Unicode standard is now widely accepted.
A wide character is of type wchar_t. A wide-character string is represented as a wchar_t[] array. You point to the array with a wchar_t* pointer.

Since this statement is from Microsoft directly, I am quite worried now:
How can a "two-byte multilingual character code" hold any character of the Unicode character set that already contains around 150,000 code points (characters)? [ Plus, if we take into account the private use code points, surrogates, code points that already have been reserved, and so on, it would be over a 1,000,000 code points? ]
I hope that this question is not a duplicate because its core is that Microsoft itself states something which seems to be plain wrong, and I really would like to know what I have misunderstood specifically on the Microsoft page I have linked.
By the way, then there is this page that contradicts the first one and eventually tells the truth:

Windows represents Unicode characters using UTF-16 encoding, in which each character is encoded as one or two 16-bit values.

So obviously, we sometimes need two wchar_t characters (4 bytes) to represent Unicode code points. Well, that would make sense somehow, but given the contradicting documentation, I am complete unsure now.
If somebody is interested in how that question originated:
In one of my projects, I have a string that must have a character at a certain fixed position replaced by another character. This happens in a loop and must be done as fast as possible. This is a no-brainer with normal char[] strings. But the string in question is of type wchar_t[], and I don't have control over the replacement characters.
Depending on which from the above Microsoft statements is true, this is either a no-brainer, too (if the first statement is true), but if the second statement is true, it would become quite a mess: I could not just replace the wchar_t character at the respective index by the replacement character, because the original character might be one wchar_t while the second might need two wchar_t, or vice versa.
That's why I'd like know which documentation is true.

Well, a 16-bit wchar_t obviously can't represent all of Unicode – but "a wide character" doesn't exactly precisely say "one wchar_t". I think that documentation has been written in an era where weird locale-specific multibyte sequences were a thing...

IIRC, MS likes to  promote UTF-16 which sometimes needs 2 wchar_t for a Unicode codepoint.

@AKX Thanks, and +1. However, they are not only speaking of "a wide character", but they are explicitly defining a wide character to be a "two-byte multilingual character code" (first sentence in first citation).

It's probably out of date text that you should give them feedback on, but if this is a practical use question the best idea might be to test it with a 3-4 byte unicode character and see what happens.   Even if it somehow works, the docs should probably be updated to be more clear.

Well, it's also possible that that documentation was written during Unicode 1.0 era. "Unicode 2.0 was released July 1996. [...] This was the first Unicode version to reserve blocks outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane."

The good thing is that the MS document repo is on github and they are usually pretty quick to accept pull requests. I've made a few corrections there after seeing questions here on SO. I'm not qualified to make this correction though. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs

Well then, thanks for the fast help. Then it boils down to that the first citation is wrong. I'll try to give them feedback (the first time).

I have submitted a correction. This text was correct at the time it was written in 1989. It became obsolete with the expansion of Unicode to supplementary planes in 1996, but this specific text was missed as part of the massive update.

There are several errors in the article. For example, "Only one locale can be represented at a time in multibyte encoding". Greetings from the UTF-8 world.

@n.m.couldbeanAI They're referring to Windows's MBCSes.

@AKX UTF-8 is one of them, for quite some time.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Well, Raymond says that the docs were written in 1989, which predates UTF-8 :)

@AKX Perhaps it was written back then, but the date on top says 2022 (last update date on github).

@n.m.couldbeanAI exactly expresses what has got me: I thought that the article might be (too) old, but then noticed that it is from 2022. Therefore I thought that the statements might be still valid.

@n.m.couldbeanAI In Windows documentation "Unicode" means "UTF-16LE" and "MBCS" means "ANSI/CP encoding". Those are the precise meanings. Debating their accuracy is moot.

@IInspectable Widows documentation is a bunch of files, some of which have not changed since the Chicxulub impact. As of Windows 10 build 1903 (May 2019), UTF-8 is one of the ANSI/CP encodings, so a MBCS.

@n.m.couldbeanAI UTF-8 as an ANSI codepage is still very much experimental. Regardless, let me make that statement more precise then: "MBCS" means "ANSI/CP encoding not including UTF-[7|8]". That's what "MBCS" means throughout all of Windows' API documentation.

The date on the page is the "last modified" date, not the "originally written" date. It was updated this morning with new text.

@RaymondChen Thank you very much! Yes, it was clear that the date on the page is the "last modified" date. But I would have expected that it is the key point of a modification to update articles so that they reflect the current situation at the modification time. Well, mistakes happen, and that is inevitable and is not a big problem as long as people deal with them in a professional manner (as in this case). Hence, thanks again for fixing it, problem solved. My biggest problem now is to decide whose answer I should mark as accepted :-)

If one of the replies answers your issue, please consider accepting it. That will help others.

@Ax1le Of course. Sorry for the delay. To be honest, it wasn't that easy to decide who I should give the answer to. All three answers (so far) are correct.


How can a "two-byte multilingual character code" hold any character of the Unicode character set that already contains around 150,000 code points (characters)?

A single 16-bit wchar_t can represent only a small fraction of all the code point values in Unicode's 21-bit code space.  There was a point early in Unicode's history when it was thought that 65536 characters (the number of distinct 16-bit values) would be enough, and that's how Java, for example, which was trying to be forward-looking, ended up with a 16-bit char type.  It didn't take long to realize, however, that 65536 was completely insufficient.  As you observe, far more code points than that are assigned today.
The Microsoft statement you quoted is wrong.
However, there is a well established mechanism (UTF-16) for encoding any Unicode code point value in at most two 16-bit code units.  This is what the Windows API in fact expects and uses for wide strings.  It is possible that the bad statement is just out of date, or that it resulted from a bad edit.  This correct variation is very similar:

Any character in use in modern computing worldwide, including technical symbols and special publishing characters, can be represented according to the Unicode specification via wide characters.

If one didn't read critically and / or was not well informed on the details of Unicode then they might not recognize that that doesn't mean the same as the original.
Side note:

In one of my projects, I have a string that must have a character at a
certain fixed position replaced by another character. This happens in
a loop and must be done as fast as possible. This is a no-brainer with
normal char[] strings.

No, it isn't.  Not at all.  Depending on the encoding with which you were representing your strings and the range of characters to be supported, you might need to deal with characters that are not supported by your encoding, or with the fact that ordinary strings can still use variable-length encodings.  In particular, UTF-8 is pretty common.  Modern C even has a syntax for UTF-8 string literals.

But the string in question is of type
wchar_t[], and I don't have control over the replacement characters.

Yes, unless the range of characters you must support is constrained in a suitable way, you need to deal with the possibility that one of the two characters involved in the replacement requires 2 units, but the other uses only one.

"that's how Java, which was trying to be forward-looking, ended up with a 16-bit char type" - Almost two years after work on Windows NT had started, one of the first operating systems that used UCS-2 as its internal encoding.

... which lends support to "It is possible that the bad statement is just out of date", @IInspectable.  But that's about how MS wound up with a false statement on their website, not about whether it is false.

@JohnBollinger No, it isn't. Not at all. Depending on the encoding [...] Well, you got me here. This example shows one more time that imprecise wording always has bad consequences. I have quite some experience with UTF-8 :-) and know about variable-length encodings (although this specific experience mainly comes from Perl in my case). What I actually meant by "normal char[] strings" is the classical char[] in the sense of old C, with one character per byte.

As discussed in the comments, my best guess is simply that that's pretty old documentation.
I dug up an old (October 1995) MSDN CD and set it up in Windows 98, and the verbiage seems pretty similar to those docs:

EDIT: The exact same text can be found at least on the VS6.0 edition of the MSDN CDs ((C) 1991-1998 Microsoft Corporation):

EDIT 2: ... and in MSVC 4.0, 1996:

Couldn't find it in MSVC 1.0 or 2.0 though.

As far as I can surmise, the Unicode encoding Microsoft used back in the day was UCS-2 (which is, AFAIU, UTF-16 but without surrogate pairs, in other words limited to the Basic Multilingual Plane's 65,536 characters).
In that context, and with a suitably narrow (pre-Unicode 2.0) view of what Unicode covers, the documentation is correct.

Thank you very much for your answer, and deepest respect for being able to dig out documentation that is over 25 years ole. Wow. If I could only give the answer to multiple people ... But at least, I can upvote your answer.

There are multiple thing around Unicode, characters and their encoding which makes it all confusing.
So, right now windows API is UTF-16, this encoding is multi byte, so there could be 1 or 2 wchars per code point. So you cannot just replace by index as you pointed, thus, it is better to trust 2nd link from your question.
But, historically UTF-16 stems from now obsolete UCS-2 encoding, which was 2 byte fixed width, each code point always was single wchar. That encoding at some point in time (roughly before 2000) was named "Unicode", this is why 1st link was true at time of writing, but not anymore.
from
https://web.archive.org/web/20030818043641/http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#23

Q: What is the difference between UCS-2 and UTF-16?


A. UCS-2 is what a Unicode implementation was up to Unicode 1.1, before surrogate code points and UTF-16 were added as concepts to Version 2.0 of the standard. This term should be now be avoided.


Just to clarify: Windows uses UTF-16LE, while UTF-16BE (or just UTF-16) is the recommended UTF-16 endianess.

I would take that more as an obfuscation, @TedLyngmo.  The label "UTF-16" does not indicate endianness, and surely native endianness is the recommended form for internal use of UTF-16.  Until one considers externalizing Unicode data, I see no reason to complicate things with considerations of non-native endianness.

@JohnBollinger I see your point. It's just that I've come across others who have stated that UTF-16 without the endianess being specified means UTF-16BE (unless there's a BOM involved). In the light of that, I prefer to say that Windows uses UTF-16LE, to avoid confusion :-)

@TedLyngmo, those others are wrong, of course.  :-)  For them: "UTF-16" means that you need either to guess or to rely on a byte-order mark.  RFC 2781 recommends -- but does not require --  guessing UTF-16BE in the absence of a BOM, but that's a far cry from "UTF-16" being synonymous with "UTF-16BE".

@JohnBollinger I can buy that! I'm leaving the comments regarding this here since I think the discussion that followed may have some value in the future. At least for me. :-)

@TedLyngmo Please leave your comments as-is. The discussion is very valuable!

@Ilya Bursov Thank you very much for your answer. That's one of those classical cases where I'd like to give the answer to multiple people, but that's not possible. But at least, I can upvote your answer :-)
